# Image caption (text) is shrinked significantly together with image

Tags: html, css

I have:

```
<div style="min-width: 1000px;">
    <p>
        Some text
    </p>
    <div class='div_img_left'>
        <img src="images/sth.png" alt="missing image" style="max-width: 100%;">
        <footer>My caption</footer>
    </div>
</div>


.div_img_left {
    max-width: 50%;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    text-align: center;    
}
```

It is looking fine on my PC's screen. The problem begins when I open it on my mobile phone. As I suppose the issue here is that I don't have 1000px screen width on the phone. So everything shrinks. The problem is that "Some text" looks fine. Unfortunately "My caption" shrinks significantly more. How can I solve this?

I tried using other geometrical constraints but I failed. Specifically using % or min-height.

Comment: Are you using the [`viewport` meta tag](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/responsive?hl=en#add-a-viewport)?

Comment: @showdev No, thank you. It seems to solve my issues. Please write it in the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Oh, great! I didn't expect that so solve all of your issues, but it's a good place to start. [That article](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/your-first-multi-screen-site/responsive) has other useful information about responsive websites, including how to use [Media Queries](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/fundamentals/use-media-queries).

Comment: @futer8 showdev hasn't posted an answer yet. I had posted my answer as  showdev was conversing with you. I don't mind if you unaccept my answer should showdev posts his.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use media queries and don't set things at such a large `min-width` if you want to have a responsive site. Use [vw](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design) for width.

```css
.div_img_left {
  max-width: 50vw;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  
}
figcaption {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  figcaption {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1
    min-width: 100%;
  }
  figure {
    min-width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <!--changed from min-width: 1000px-->
  <p>
    Some text
  </p>
  <figure class='div_img_left'>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x200/eea/e00?text=150x200" alt="missing image" style="max-width: 100%;">
    <figcaption>My caption</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```